# Minvol bounded below by characteristic numbers: Why?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology

For a closed smooth oriented manifold $M$, define
$$
\text{Minvol}(M) = \inf_{g: \substack{|K_g| \le 1\\g \text{ complete}}} \text{vol}_g(M),
$$
where $|K_g|$ here denotes $\sup_{p \in M}\sup_{\Pi \text{ plane in }T_pM}|K_g(\Pi)|$ (whre $K_g$ is the sectional curvature).

In [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1982__56__5_0.pdf) by Gromov (top of Pg 3 of the PDF aka Pg 6 of the File),
it is stated that "by Gauss-Bonnet", for every $n$,
for we have some constants $c_n > 0$, $c'_n > 0$ such that
for every closed smooth (oriented) $M$ of dimension $n$,

1. $\text{Minvol}(M) \ge c_n|\chi(M)|$,
2. $\text{Minvol}(M) \ge c'_n|p(M)|$ for the Pontyagin number**s** $p(M)$ of $M$.

The question is: Apart from the most naive case (i.e. $n = 2$, which applies to case 1.), how do we see this? Is the proof written down anywhere?

Comment: Small quibble: your quantifiers are somewhat out of order. Specifically, the way you have phrased things suggests that the constants depend on $M$, which of course renders the statement trivial.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks, my bad, that wasn't my intention. I have fixed the description.

Comment: Anyway, I've worked out the reasons. (But I'm not sure how to delete the post)

Comment: For any metric $g$, let $\Omega$ be the corresponding (sectional) curvature 2-form. Let $\{\partial_{x_1},\ldots,\partial_{x_n}\}$ be an orthonormal frame wrt $g$. In this frame, $\Omega = \sum_{1 \le i < j \le 2n} \Omega_{ij} dx_i \wedge dx_j$. 
If $|K_g| \le 1$, then $|\Omega_{ij}| \le 1$, and thus $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n \cdot n!}\text{vol}_g(M) \ge |\int_M \text{Pf}(\Omega)| = v_{2n} \cdot |\chi(M)|$, where $v_{2n}$ is a constant only depending on $n$ (given by Chern GBT).
Taking inf on both sides yields the desired result.

Comment: 2. is similar, just replace $\text{Pf}$ by another invariant polynomial (and a result similar to Chern GBT).